# Can't run Child Component method in Parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to run Child component method in Parent Component. It's not official but I need to run this for complicated code... I try to use `refs` but it is not working in Parent Component. The error below occurs.

> Cannot read property 'renderSetup' of undefined

Parent Component:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._renderSetup = this._renderSetup.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._renderSetup();
  }


  _renderSetup() {
    this.refs.Child.renderSetup();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child ref={Child} />
    )
  }
```

Child Component

```
class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderSetup = this.renderSetup.bind(this);
  }

  renderSetup = () => {
     // complicated code
  }
```

Comment: `ref` prop have to look like `ref="Child"` (btw, this is legacy API)

Comment: Next its error occurs, `Cannot read property 'renderSetup' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ref` attribute is a special property that you can't access via `props`. To use `ref` on a component, you can wrap it with [`React.forwardRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html):

```js
const { Component, createRef } = React;

class _Child extends Component {
  constructor(props, ...args) {
    super(props, ...args);
    
    if(props.forwardedRef) {
      props.forwardedRef.current = {
        renderSetup: this.renderSetup
      };
    }
  }

  renderSetup = () => {
     console.log('renderSetup');
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>Child</div>;
  }
}

const Child = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <_Child {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />
));

class Parent extends Component {
  childRef = createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    this._renderSetup();
  }


  _renderSetup = () => {
    if(this.childRef.current) {
      this.childRef.current.renderSetup();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child ref={this.childRef} />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call a method of a child, you probably need to rethink your solution...

In React, the data is transmitted in the hierarchy like this:

```
Parent ---(props)--> Child

Parent <--(events)-- Child
```

Your component should render the output HTML based on some kind of state, **not a call from a function**.

However the following is very well accepted:

```
Parent --> calls some function

function --> changes some state

Child --> renders the content based on that state
```

This can be done with **Redux or ContextAPI**, where you can store a global state, change it within any component you want, and the child component which is listening to that global state, re-renders when the state changes.

If you don't want to use Redux or ContextAPI however, you can use normal props:

**Parent component:**

```
class Parent extends Component {
    state = {
        renderChildSetup: false
    }

    handleSomeEvent: () => {
        this.setState({ renderChildSetup: true });
    }

    render () {
        return <Child renderSetup={this.state.renderChildSetup} />
    }
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
class Child extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>

                ...

                this.props.renderSetup ? <Setup /> : null

                ...

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. Actually, I need to study more about Redux and React. Anyway I appreciate it!

Comment: if you’re looking for something more straightforward, just take a look at React’s built in context API.